# fixed size memory allocator interface without fragmentation on freeing the memory

Tags: c

I was trying to write a memory pool interface which:

1. Grants memory of fixed size chunks in linked list style fashion.
2. On returning the memory there is no risk of memory fragmentation.

   ```
   //mem_struct.h
   #ifndef MEM_STRUCT_H
   #define MEM_STRUCT_H

   struct mem_struct
   {
      char arr[4];
      struct mem_struct *next;
   };

   #endif
   ```

Now using above structure the interface will grant memory to the user (the function which demands memory):

```
//mem_allocator.c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"mem_struct.h"
#define total 10     //max no. of fixed size memory blocks initialized at once in a pool

unsigned int total_pool_size=0;   //total bytes of memory in pool available
struct mem_struct *head=NULL;     //first node of memory pool

/* function to initialize memory pool of max total no. of memory blocks or less if memory not 
   available and add newly allocated blocks to existing memory pool blocks */
int mem_pool_init()
{
   struct mem_struct *temp;
   unsigned short count = 0; //no. of memory blocks/chunks successfully allocated and added to existing memory pool

   while(count < total)
   {
      temp = calloc(1,sizeof(*temp));
      if(temp)
      {
         temp->next = head;
         head = temp;
         total_pool_size += sizeof(temp->arr);
         count++;
      }
      else
         return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}


//function which grants memory in bytes to the user request 
void* mem_grant(unsigned int siz)   
{
    struct mem_struct *temp_head = NULL;  //pointer to first block of memory to be returned to the requesting function
    if(siz > 0)
    {
       //This loop will go on till there is sufficient memory in the memory pool to allocate memory of size - siz or the CPU is left with no memory 
       while(total_pool_size < siz)
           if(mem_pool_init())
              return NULL;

       struct mem_struct *temp = head;
       unsigned int total_nodes = 0;   //total no of nodes of memory to be returned to the requesting function

       if(total_pool_size >= siz)
       {
          temp_head = head;

          if(siz%sizeof(temp_head->arr) > 0) //to determine no. of memory blocks to be returned to the user request
             total_nodes = siz/sizeof(temp_head->arr) + 1;
          else
             total_nodes = siz/sizeof(temp_head->arr);

          while(total_nodes)
          {
              temp = temp->next;  
              --total_nodes;
              total_pool_size = total_pool_size - sizeof(temp->arr);
          }
          head = temp->next;
          temp->next = NULL;
       }
   }
   return (void *)temp_head;
}


//function to add the memory earlier allocated back to the memory block
void free_mem(void *temp_head) //temp_head points to the first byte of the memory allocated to the user using mem_grant
{
    if(temp_head)
    {
        struct mem_struct *temp = *temp_head;
    
        while(temp)
        {
           memset(temp,0,sizeof(temp->arr));

           if(!temp->next)
           {
               temp->next = head;
               break;
           }
           total_pool_size += sizeof(temp->arr);
        }
        head = temp_head;
    }
}
```

Here is the `main` function:

```
//main.c
#include<stdio.h>

extern void* mem_grant(unsigned int);
extern void  free_mem(void*);
extern unsigned int total_pool_size;

int main()
{
    void* ptr = mem_grant(42);
    if(ptr)
        printf("total_pool_size after grant %u\n", total_pool_size);
    free_mem(ptr);
    printf("total_pool_size after free %u\n", total_pool_size);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to this part of programming and I want to know how can I improve as I don't have any reference material to lookup. Could someone please review this and tell me how this design is?

Comment: Welcome to code review. Could you please provide the `main()` program or the function that calls these functions. Right now this code is without context and we can't do a good review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I have added the main function along with few minor edits.

Comment: Can you fix up the indentation in your code? It seems a little random, particularly in `mem_allocator.c`.

Comment: @Reinderien Corrected it, Did you review this code?

Comment: Please don't touch the code after answers have come. While the latest edit doesn't invalidate the existing answer, there's always a risk involved.

Comment: @Mast Will not touch, just changes a comment. Thanks

Comment: Please do not change the code after the question is answered. The last edit deleted a lot of code. See our [rules](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts as I read through your post:

> On returning the memory there is no risk of memory fragmentation

I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you mean that all the memory will be `free` i.e. not leaked?  I don't see anything related to memory fragmentation.

---

```
char arr[4];
```

I don't know your use case, but 4 bytes is very small for a modern computer.  You could easily spend 100 times longer dereferencing a pointer than reading 4 bytes.  Are you sure a linked list is the right choice here?

---

```
struct mem_struct *head=NULL;
```

If someone else makes a global variable named `head` in another .c file, then you will get a linker error because of duplicate symbols.  If you have to use a global variable, you should name it something distinctive like

```
struct mem_struct *global_mem_struct_head=NULL;
```

But a better idea is not to use a global variable at all, and pass a `mem_struct*` argument to each function.

---

```
//max no. of fixed size memory blocks initialized at once in a pool
#define total 10
```

How about this:

```
static const int max_init_memory_blocks = 10;
```

Now you effectively get the comment every time you use the variable, you get type checking, and even though this is a global, it's invisible outside of this translation unit/this file.

That said, you've done a good job adding comments throughout your code.

---

```
int mem_pool_init()
```

This function does initialization a fixed number of times.  Can you use a for loop?

---

```
calloc
```

If calloc succeeds and then fails, you'll leak the first allocations.

---

```
void* mem_grant
```

Why does this return `void*`?!  How is the user supposed to know they can only use the first few bytes?!

---

```
   while(total_pool_size < siz)   //insufficient memory in pool
       if(mem_pool_init())
          return NULL;
```

Isn't this an infinite loop?

---

I'm going to stop here.  I think you would find a lot of these mistakes with some very simple test cases.  Then you can post an improved version.

Comment: Your point about name conflicts of global symbols is correct, but your solution (assuming we keep the global) is not. The real solution is to make the symbol non-exported, i.e. `static`.

Comment: This is just a trial version hence I have used small size i.e. `arr[4]`. You are right, I should've used `static` to restrict the use of  `*`head` to this transactional unit.

Comment: The `while` loop keeps adding **10** nodes to the existing memory linked list until and unless the linked list have more than or equal to the no. of nodes requested i.e. `siz`. hence this is the loop which already governs `int mem_pool_init()`.

Comment: Even if I allocate a big chunk of memory per node, say 1024 bytes per node then if I require only 1200 bytes then 848 bytes will be wasted - this fixed size allocation have some big drawbacks though there is no fragmentation involved as the `free`d memory is appended to the memory pool linked list

Comment: @Konrad since the driver code accesses `head`, I don't think it should be `static`.

Comment: @Agrudge thanks for commenting; I see the the loop will terminate.  It would be nice if you could tell the loop terminated just by reading those lines and which being familiar with the internals of other functions.  Freeing all the memory you allocate will prevent memory leaks, but there's no guarantee it will prevent fragmentation.

Comment: @sudo What do you mean by that? What driver? `head` is only accessed inside a single translation unit. It’s a prime candidate for `static`-ness.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash On `free`-ing the memory the free nodes will be appended to the existing chain of available memory pool linked list - hence the memory available (linked list) will always be continuous (the linked list is a chain which is continuous even when the nodes are not in continuous memory location). Due to this there will be no fragmentation.

Comment: @Konrad sorry you're right. Feel free to edit the answer.  I thought that it was used in the driver code but it's not.